# How to define a global variable in launch.json in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In the VSCode's lauch.json file, I use multiple configurations for debugging different files. And some of these variables are common between configurations.
I wonder if this could be possible to define a global variable in the launch.json and use it in different locations of the file?

For example, I'm looking for a way to define `variable_common` once and use it in `config 1` and `config 2`:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: config 1",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["variable_1", "variable_2", "variable_common"]
        },

        {
            "name": "Python: config 2",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["variable_3", "variable_4", "variable_common"]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#transform) you can create custom variables

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: config 1",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true,
      "args": ["variable_1", "variable_2", "${input:VAR_COMMON}"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: config 2",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true,
      "args": ["variable_3", "variable_4", "${input:VAR_COMMON}"]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "VAR_COMMON",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "common_arg" }
    }
  ]
}
```